# Break single line varchar into multiple in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a single `nvarchar` column in SQL Server 2008 that has data in a comma delimited list that looks like this:

```
NM=John, AD=994 Fake Avenue, CY=Las Vegas, ST=NV, ZC=85144, ZX=1299, RAD=994 Fake Avenue, RCY=Las Vegas, RST=NV, RZC=85144, RZX=1299, BD=1/1/2001
```

I need to break up the individual elements into individual variables in SQL so I can output the address like this:

```
Residence Address:
994 Fake Avenue
Las Vegas NV 85114

Mailing Address:
994 Fake Avenue
Las Vegas NV 85114
```

Mailing address is AD, CY, ST, ZC, and ZX. Residence is the fields RAD, RCY, RST, RZC, RZX. I only want the address info. There may be other fields mentioned in the string that I don't care about such as something like BD= or NM=. Only the specific address fields I would want to be stripped out.

I would think I need to use ltrim, rtrim, and replace functions but I am not quite sure how to tie it together. Thank you.

Comment: Do you really have this stored in a single column? This is just awful to work with. Any chance you can fix the design so this is properly normalized? What you really have here a comma delimited EAV string. Ugh!!!

Comment: Yes it is in a single column. This is how data is stored in a table called LOG. This data represents old data before change took place, that is why it's in that format.

Comment: Are these values always in the same order or can they move around row to row? I know the position of each value moves within the row but if the the 12 values are always in the same order it will make this a little easier.

Comment: They will not always be in the same order. I just want to say ok this is the address, place it here, this the city, place it here, etc.

Comment: Right but you have to parse this and if they are in the same order it would be a little easier. Can still be done just a lot more code to pull off. More challenging is you have AD= and RAD=. That will make charindex uselss here because it would return for both values.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're in 2008, you don't have the SPLIT_STRING function built in, so you'll need to write your own using something like [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).

Split the string on commas and store the results into a table. Split each substring on the equals sign to get your identifier and value pairs, and insert those into a secondary table. From there, use a case statement to determine what value you're looking at, and assemble them in order to construct your address.

Comment: Yikes. Please don't use that splitter. It is horrific for performance. A much better option is Jeff Moden's found here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/. Or a few other choices here. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings Looping should be avoided for this type of an operation.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks. I generally would do this operation outside of the database, but in trying to provide a T-SQL option, I went with the first option that came up without considering performance. I've updated the link to Jeff Moden's code.

Comment: Yes I saw that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is to use a little XML

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int, SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'NM=John, AD=994 Fake Avenue, CY=Las Vegas, ST=NV, ZC=85144, ZX=1299, RAD=994 Fake Avenue, RCY=Las Vegas, RST=NV, RZC=85144, RZX=1299, BD=1/1/2001')


Select  ID
       ,NM = XMLData.value('row[1]/@NM[1]','varchar(max)')
       ,AD = XMLData.value('row[1]/@AD[1]','varchar(max)')
       ,CY = XMLData.value('row[1]/@CY[1]','varchar(max)')
       ,ST = XMLData.value('row[1]/@ST[1]','varchar(max)')
       ,ZC = XMLData.value('row[1]/@ZC[1]','varchar(max)')
       ,RAD = XMLData.value('row[1]/@RAD[1]','varchar(max)')
       ,RCY = XMLData.value('row[1]/@RCY[1]','varchar(max)')
       ,RST = XMLData.value('row[1]/@RST[1]','varchar(max)')
       ,RZC = XMLData.value('row[1]/@RZC[1]','varchar(max)')
       ,RZX = XMLData.value('row[1]/@RZX[1]','varchar(max)')
       ,BD  = XMLData.value('row[1]/@BD[1]','varchar(max)')
 From (
        Select ID
              ,XMLData=cast('<row '+replace(replace(SomeCol,'=','="'),', ','" ')+'"/>' as xml)
         From @YourTable
      ) A
```

**Returns**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here is splitting these values into something usable. Here is how you can do that fairly easily using the Jeff Moden string splitter. You can find that splitter here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Then we need to use conditional aggregation and some string manipulation to finish this off. The code below will parse this into columns for each of the values you are looking for. And it does not matter what order these appear in your string. And if one row doesn't have a value this will simply return NULL.

```
declare @Something table
(
    SomeValue varchar(500)
)

insert @Something select 'NM=John, AD=994 Fake Avenue, CY=Las Vegas, ST=NV, ZC=85144, ZX=1299, RAD=994 Fake Avenue, RCY=Las Vegas, RST=NV, RZC=85144, RZX=1299, BD=1/1/2001'
;

with FirstParse as
(
    select ltrim(split.Item) as Item
    from @Something s
    cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(s.SomeValue, ',') split
)
, ParsedValues as
(
    select Property = left(fp.Item, charindex('=', fp.Item) - 1)
        , Value = substring(fp.Item, charindex('=', fp.Item) + 1, len(fp.Item))
    from FirstParse fp
)

select Name = max(case when Property = 'NM' then Value end)
    , ResidenceAddress = max(case when Property = 'AD' then Value end)
    , ResidenceCity = max(case when Property = 'CY' then Value end)
    , ResidenceState = max(case when Property = 'ST' then Value end)
    , ResidenceZip = max(case when Property = 'ZC' then Value end)
    , Address = max(case when Property = 'RAD' then Value end)
    , City = max(case when Property = 'RCY' then Value end)
    , State = max(case when Property = 'RST' then Value end)
    , Zip = max(case when Property = 'RZC' then Value end)
from ParsedValues
```